# Terminal command or keyboard shortcut for opening the indicator applet

Tags: command-line, indicator, applet

I wanna configure my top right corner as a hot corner that opens the indicator applet, but I can't find the command to execute that action.
Does anybody know which one it is?

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following commands will open the "User menu", which is what the "indicator applet" on the right hand corner is referred to by the Gnome developpers:

```
gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.Shell -o /org/gnome/Shell -m org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.toggle();'
```

or

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.open();'
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT,  IT WORKS!

Comment: If it works, please then express your thanks by accepting the answer: click the checkmark next to the question. That also shows other users that a useful answer may be available.